# How can I download FULL QUALITY pictures from google images using puppeteer?

Tags: node.js, axios, puppeteer, cheerio

Need help in how to create a stable selector that saves URL in full quality from google images.

Trying to download 4-25 pictures from google images using puppeteer in full quality.
It doesn't work.
The problem is to create a stable selector and getting URLs of the pictures in full quality and not the URL of google's preview mode.

I had it running already but it broke down due to what I understand to be a not so well selector. Now trying rebuild it.

Old selector that results in "elements" being undefined:

```
let previewimagexpath =
      "/html/body/div[2]/c-wiz/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/c-wiz/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/a/img";
    // previewimagexpath = '//*[@id="Sva75c"]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/c-wiz/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/a/img'
    for (let i = 1; i < numOfPics; i++) {
      let imagexpath =
        "/html/body/div[2]/c-wiz/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/span/div[1]/div[1]/div[" +
        i +
        "]/a[1]/div[1]/img";
      const elements = await page.$x(imagexpath);
      await elements[0].click(); 
      await page.waitForTimeout(3000);
      const image = await page.$x(previewimagexpath);
      let d = await image[0].getProperty("src");
      //console.log(d._remoteObject.value);
      imagelinkslist.push(d._remoteObject.value);
    }
    await browser.close();
  };
```

new selector which is resulting in URLs of the preview mode and not in URLs of full quality images.

```
axios
  .get(
    "https://www.google.com/search?q=dogs&sxsrf=ALiCzsZW27NYppMFDO9xwabkhmXUQMku8g:1651495383126&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj4-qLd68D3AhUR3KQKHdk3CFYQ_AUoAXoECAIQAw&biw=1680&bih=948&dpr=2"
  )
  .then(response => {
    const $ = cheerio.load(response.data);
    const image = $("img");
    $("img").each((i, elem) => {});
    console.log(image);
  });
```

Comment: Why is this tagged Puppeteer and max/msp? I see no sign of Puppeteer and max/msp is DSP software that has nothing to do with JS. Please specify which URLs you're expecting to get. Thanks.

Comment: Edited. hopefully the Puppeteer is clear now.
As for Max/MSP, it's node.js running from within max (N4M). But probably not relevant.